# Getting the name of the last mounted/unmounted filesystem

Tags: linux, polling, mount

I know I can monitor (using [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), or [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)) on the files `/proc/mount` or `/etc/mtab` and findout **WHEN** a filesystem is mounted or unmounted. Also I can use [getmntent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html) for getting a list of mounted filesystems.

My app is intended to monitor the mounted filesystem and report any change (mount or unmount).

My solution:

1. Detect some change in `/proc/mounts`.
2. Get all currently mounted filesystem with `getmntent`.
3. Compare the obtained list with some previous list.
4. Process the difference.

But I need to know if there are some way to get the last filesystem mounted when polling from `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab`. Just reading the file or polling data into some structure (like `mntent` for instance.)

Comment: As a side note, if you use systemd, you can subscribe for unit change notifications (.mount units) an you'll get what you need easily.

Comment: Yes I'm using systemd. Can you explain a little more on `subscribe for unit change notifications (.mount units)` ?

Comment: systemd notifies of any changes in the units, including mount points, through its dbus public interface. I have written a sample code similar to what you need, in Python, [here](https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2014-February/035041.html). Maybe you can use it as a base for your problem.

Comment: you got some advance with your problem?

Comment: Yes, but I had to go with a solution that uses udev incombination with monitoring /etc/mtab

Answer (score 0):

## Solution description

The implemented solution involve [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), [setmntent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setmntent) and [getmntent](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent).

The idea is to keep a list of all the mounted file systems (this is not memory-expensive, since the number of devices is generally low) and the list has to be created only once.

Using *poll()* over *"/proc/mounts"* you can find out **when** a filesystem is mounted or unmounted. And then using udev you can get the list of devices mounted at that time. So you can compare with the list you already have and that way you will know if the filesystem was mounted or unmounted and which filesystem is the affected.

## Relevant code samples of the soultion

Function to get the mounted nodes.

```
vector<string> get_mounted_storage_nodes()
{
    vector<string> storage_nodes = get_storage_nodes(); // This uses udev.
    vector<string> mounted_nodes;
    struct mntent *mntent;

    FILE *file;
    file = setmntent("/etc/mtab", "r");

    while ((mntent = getmntent(file)))
    {
        string mounted_node(mntent->mnt_fsname);
        vector<string>::iterator it;
        it = find(storage_nodes.begin(), storage_nodes.end(), mounted_node);
        if (it != storage_nodes.end())
            mounted_nodes.push_back(mounted_node);
    }

    return mounted_nodes;
}
```

### Finding out if the filesystem was mounted or unmounted

Simple just compare the size of both lits.

```
// event is a convenience struct that holds the name of the affected
// filesystem and the action (mounted or unmounted).

vector<string> new_mounted_nodes = get_mounted_storage_nodes();
int new_size = new_mounted_nodes.size();
int curr_size = mounted_nodes.size();

if (new_size == curr_size)
    event.action = NONE;    // No partition was mount or unmounted.
                            // This case is very common when the poll
                            // is working as non-blocking because the timeout.
else
    event.action = new_size > curr_size ? MOUNT : UMOUNT;
```

### Finding out if the affected filesystem

```
vector<string> new_mounted_nodes = get_mounted_storage_nodes();
```

Using the previous line, if the filesystem was mounted, you only have to find the element of `new_mounted nodes` that is not in the list of mounted nodes you already have. On the other hand, if the filesystem was unmounted you have to find the element that is in the list you already have but not in `new_mounted_nodes`.

**Code sample:**

```
switch(event.action)
{
    case MOUNT:

        for (auto it = new_mounted_nodes.begin(); it != new_mounted_nodes.end(); ++it)
            if (find(mounted_nodes.begin(), mounted_nodes.end(), *it) == mounted_nodes.end())
            {
                event.node = *it;
                break;
            }
        break;

    case UMOUNT:
        for (auto it = mounted_nodes.begin(); it != mounted_nodes.end(); ++it)
            if (find(new_mounted_nodes.begin(), new_mounted_nodes.end(), *it) == new_mounted_nodes.end())
            {
                event.node = *it;
                break;
            }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The complexity of the latest code is **O(n^2)**, but the number of mounted devices will generally (I don't want to be absolute) be lower that 20. So, the algorithm will run very fast.